# How to hide Navigation Bar on Orientation Change with 'react-navigation?'

Tags: react-native, react-router, react-native-navigation

i am currently working on an App for Android and iOS -  i am using react native.
Is there any way to hide the navigation bar dynamically in react-navigation or should i rather switch to react native router flux?
When the user changes to landscape i want to hide the navigation bar, when he goes back to Portrait, i want to show it again.

I know how to change it statically by using {header: null} in the navigation Options, but this does not help me in this case, at least i did not find a way to solve this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a hack but I think you can replace the provided header component from React navigation with your own, then add a redux state that controls its visibility.

Either wrap your screens with a view that contains an onLayout event that will trigger redux action to set the visibility of your custom header.

Comment: Have you found a solution ?